# Inspecting an implicit Exception when debugging inside a raise block

Tags: ruby, exception, ruby-debug

I'm using ruby-debug to dive into code that's throwing and silently eating exceptions. (The code is inside a gem, so I'm loathe to edit it directly without a really good reason.)

I get to this line:

```
   167        def catch_exceptions
   168          begin
   169            yield
   170          rescue Exception
=> 171            rollback
   172          end
   173        end
   174
```

As line 170 isn't defined as `rescue Exception => e`, there's no exception object declared.

**Is there a way of inspecting this "implicit" exception object?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the most recent exception using the global variable `$!`.

I know you don't always have a choice but consider fixing the gem or using a different one. That catch-all approach is really bad when it comes to tracing down exceptions.